# How do I delete all lines in a file starting from after a matching line?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file which is made up of several lines of text:

```
The first line
The second line
The third line
The fourth line
```

I have a string which is one of the lines: `The second line`

I want to delete the string and all lines after it in the file, so it will delete `The third line` and `The fourth line` in addition to the string. The file would become:

```
The first line
```

I've searched for a solution on google, and it seems that I should use `sed`. Something like:

```
sed 'linenum,$d' file
```

But how to find the line number of the string? Or, how else should I do it?

Comment: Your problem statement is contradictory: 'I want to delete all lines **after** the line' means you delete just two lines (as you say), but then your example output shows the match line as missing too.  Which do you actually want?

Comment: The matching line AND the all the lines after it. I should improve my English. Thanks for your information.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364951/remove-all-lines-before-a-match-with-sed

Comment: If I don't want to delete the line I search, then how to make it?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

If you don't want to print the matched line (or any following lines):

```
sed -n '/The second line/q;p' inputfile
```

This says "when you reach the line that matches the pattern quit, otherwise print each line". The `-n` option prevents implicit printing and the `p` command is required to explicitly print lines.

or

```
sed '/The second line/,$d' inputfile
```

This says "delete all lines from the output starting at the matched line and continuing to the end of the file".

but the first one is faster. However it will quit processing completely so if you have multiple files as arguments, the ones after the first matching file won't be processed. In this case, the delete form is better.

If you do want to print the matched line, but not any following lines:

```
sed '/The second line/q' inputfile
```

This says "print all lines and quit when the matched line is reached" (the `-n` option (no implicit print) is not used).

See [man sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) for additional information.

Comment: But some commands get antsy about broken pipes (RCS `co -p` for example), and then you are better off with the `sed '/The second line/,$d'` notation.

Comment: the first method print out the last line before matched line twice. deleting the `p` after `;` works.

Comment: @CrazyFrog: No. It doesn't. If you remove the `p`, _nothing_ gets printed. Note the `-n`.

Comment: If several files are given as an argument, e.g. to substitute in place with the -i argument, only the first file is modified. I think it might be worth mentioning it - it surely would have been good to know for me.

Comment: @FerdinandoRandisi: If you use the `q` (quit) command, `sed` is going to quit altogether, not just for that file. The `d` form will allow processing to continue to the next file. I'll add that information to my answer.

Comment: I had to add -nr for regex to match any amount of spaces in the line I wanted to match.

Comment: @BrianWiley: There must have been more to it since neither of those options have an effect like you describe without also changing the regex. The `-n` option wouldn't be involved at all (it disables automatic output) and the `-r` (or `-E`) option enables enhanced regexes but doesn't otherwise do anything.

Comment: When I turn `The second line` into a variable in `sed "/$match/,$d" inputfile`, the expected effect cannot be achieved. Do I need to treat commas specially?

Comment: @moluzhui: When you changed the quotes from single to double so the `$match` variable can be evaluated it made the sequence `$d` appear to also be a variable which likely evaluates to an empty string or some arbitrary residual value. Escaping that dollar sign should make it work again: `sed "/$match/,\$d" inputfile`. The comma doesn't change its meaning. It's an address separator.

Answer (score 46):

This is a bit shorter than other given solutions.
Quit using capital Q avoids printing the current line.

```
 sed '/The second line/Q' file
```

To actually delete the lines you can use the same syntax.

```
 sed -i '/The second line/Q' file
```

Comment: This is by far my favorite solution.

Answer (score 6):

```
sed '/The second line/q0' file
```

Or, without gnu sed:

```
sed '/The second line/q' file
```

Or, using grep:

```
grep -B 9999999 "The second line"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!Can you tell me how I can find the line number of a specific string, which I still dont know.

Comment: grep -n "The second line" file | awk -F : '{print $1}'

Comment: @DocWiki: you don't need the line number; you search for it.  `sed "/$string/,\$d" inputfile`.

Answer (score 6):

Using awk (not showing the matched line)

```
awk '/pattern/ {exit} {print}' file.txt
```

Comment: This is the best answer, since you might not know the value of the second line.

Answer (score 2):

First add the line number and delete the line

```
cat new.txt 
The first line
The second line
The third line
The fourth line

 cat new.txt  | nl
     1  The first line
     2  The second line
     3  The third line
     4  The fourth line



cat new.txt  | nl | sed  "/2/d"
     1  The first line
     3  The third line
     4  The fourth line

cat new.txt  |  nl |sed  "3d;4d"
     1  The first line
     2  The second line
```

using awk

```
awk 'NR!=3 && NR!=4' new.txt 
The first line
The second line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/The second line/{exit}1' file
```