# Stop printing to standart output after reaching pattern

Tags: cat

How can i stop printing after the file has reached the pattern ?

```
pattern='...........'
cat file | <command> $pattern
```

example:
file contents :

```
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
.........
bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
.237813981238
```

desired output :

```
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: In your question you have written `aaaaa`, `bbbb`, `.....` etc. in different lines. But notice how the parser has changed that into one line with fields separated by a space. Does your pattern, and each line you have written, represent one different line in the file? If so, please use 4 spaces before each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pattern is indeed one line in the file, then your question is a duplicate of [question 5227295](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227295/how-do-i-delete-all-lines-in-a-file-starting-from-after-a-matching-line):

```
 cat file | sed -n '/_pattern_/q;p'
```

Notice you may need to escape some characters in `_pattern_` in order to make it work as expected (i.e. if your pattern has dots as in `....`, you should write `\.\.\.\.`).

If your pattern may be in the middle of one line, then, in pure Bash:

```
contents=$(<file)
echo "${contents%%_pattern_*}"
```

Use `...........` (or your pattern) instead of `_pattern_`. Notice this time you do not need to scape the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export PATTERN_ESCAPED=`echo $PATTERN | sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g'`
cat file | sed -r 's/'"$PATTERN_ESCAPED"'.*//'
```

The first line escapes all symbols that may be used as part of regex. The second replaces the pattern and all symbols after it by nothing.