# Delete all text below a match - sed

Tags: macos, sed

I have a large text file. I would like to delete all the lines of of text below a certain phrase. For instance in this text:

> Once upon a time.
>
> There were three little pigs. They grew up to be terrible craftsmen
>   and in any event one or more of them died in obscurity.
>
> I also have a story about foxes. Some foxes are faster than other
>   foxes. Some foxes are hopeless romantics.

I would delete all the text below "Once upon a time".

I am using this as guidance [How do I delete all lines in a file starting from after a matching line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227295/how-do-i-delete-all-lines-in-a-file-starting-from-after-a-matching-line) and tried the following:

```
sed -i.bak '/Once upon a time/,$ d' /Users/auser/folder/folder/output.txt
```

But I end up with my entire text file being empty (vs. just the text below the match).

Also, I'm using a Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i.bak '/Once upon a time./q' file
```